# Method that returns the line number for a given JTextPane position?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtextpane

I'm looking for a method that computes the line number of a given text position in a JTextPane with wrapping enabled.

Example:

> This a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.
>   This is another very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long line.**|**

The cursor is on line number four, not two.

Can someone provide me with the implementation of the method:

```
int getLineNumber(JTextPane pane, int pos)
{
     return ???
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
 /**
   * Return an int containing the wrapped line index at the given position
   * @param component JTextPane
   * @param int pos
   * @return int
   */
  public int getLineNumber(JTextPane component, int pos) 
  {
    int posLine;
    int y = 0;

    try
    {
      Rectangle caretCoords = component.modelToView(pos);
      y = (int) caretCoords.getY();
    }
    catch (BadLocationException ex)
    {
    }

    int lineHeight = component.getFontMetrics(component.getFont()).getHeight();
    posLine = (y / lineHeight) + 1;
    return posLine;
  }
```

Comment: the jtextpane class is capable of supporting variable font sizes, this method WILL fail on that scenario.

Answer (score 6):

http://java-sl.com/tip_row_column.html
An alternative which works with text fragments formatted with different styles

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
public int getLineNumberAt(JTextPane pane, int pos) {
    return pane.getDocument().getDefaultRootElement().getElementIndex(pos);
}
```

Keep in mind that line numbers always start at 0.