# JTextPane - How can I create a scrolling log

Tags: java, swing, logging, jtextpane

I'm using a JTextPane (in a JScrollPane) as part of a custom logging system. (I needed multi-colour output so couldn't use JTextArea.)

I have the logging part of it working, but I now need to be able to limit its content so that it doesn't just grow in memory continuously.

There is no direct user input as all logs are system generated.

What I need to be able to do is to identify when the JTextPane had reached a specified number of lines, and then be able to delete the first line when the maximum is exceeded. This would allow me to keep a buffer of the last 'x' lines in the display.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/102171/307767

Comment: I'd already seen that post and that doesn't solve my question. I need to be able to remove a line once the entire log exceeds a number of lines.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6316272/).  I believe Message Console fits your requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use DocumentFilter and check the Document's length. Also you can use Document's getText() method and count "\n" chars in  the String.
Or you can override insertString() method of the document. If max possible amount of lines is achieved just call remove() and then super.insertString()

Answer (score 1):

try this little Example:

```
public class Example {

    private static int MAX = 7;

    static public void main( String[] s ) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

        UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName() );

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds( 50, 50, 200, 300 );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        final JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();

        pane.setText( "1\n2\n3\n4" );

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        pnl.add( pane, BorderLayout.CENTER );

        pane.getDocument().addDocumentListener( new DocumentListener() {
            public void removeUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
            }
            public void insertUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            View baseView = pane.getUI().getRootView( pane );
                            View root = baseView.getView(0);
                            for( int i = 0; i < root.getViewCount()-MAX; i++ ) {
                                int line = root.getViewIndex( i, Bias.Forward );
                                View lineview = root.getView(line);
                                pane.getDocument().remove( lineview.getStartOffset(), lineview.getEndOffset() );
                            }
                        } catch( BadLocationException e1 ) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } );
            }
            public void changedUpdate( DocumentEvent e ) {
            }
        });

        pnl.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Delete") {
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
               try {
                   View baseView = pane.getUI().getRootView( pane );
                   View root = baseView.getView(0);
                   int line = root.getViewIndex( 0, Bias.Forward );
                   View lineview = root.getView(line);
                   pane.getDocument().remove( lineview.getStartOffset(), lineview.getEndOffset() );
               } catch( BadLocationException e1 ) {
                   e1.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pnl.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Add") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent e ) {
                try {
                    pane.getDocument().insertString(pane.getDocument().getEndPosition().getOffset(), new SimpleDateFormat("ss").format( new Date() )+": This is a new line\n", null);
                } catch( BadLocationException e1 ) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setContentPane( pnl );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }
}
```